# PC freezes randomly for a second and continues to work

Tags: ubuntu, memory, freeze, intel-core-i5

I have bought a used core i5 3210/ 8GB RAM pc from a friend.
But it freezes randomly for like one seconds or less and then continues to work. 
for example, if I'm typing something in the terminal it takes what I type and then proceed all the commands at once.

Can you help me find out what causes this little freeze?

I have erased the hard-disk and reinstalled a fresh copy of ubuntu so I'm pretty sure it's not a software-related problem.

Comment: I'd first check the memory of the system using memtest or whatever tools are available. It is always a good idea to run hardware test first in used pc before purchasing or go with other diagnoses.

Comment: can bad memory cause little freezes?

Comment: Bad memory can cause a lot of problems or show symptoms. Little freezing is one of those symptoms. Since you've erased hard-disk and reinstalled a fresh copy of Ubuntu, I'd say it's more likely that you've hardware issue. So it's better if you make sure first that your hardware is fine.

Comment: Also, install the `smartmontools` package and look at the [SMART data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) of your disk.

Comment: don't you think guys it's a CPU / cooling problem?

Comment: It may be if you feel that you're pc is unusually hot or fan creates more noise. Most of the pc vendors nowadays (Dell & HP) have inbuilt hardware diagnostic option in BIOS which you can use to check your overall status of your PC including motherboard & cooling system. As my first comment, I still urge you to do overall hardware test first before you jump to other conclusions.

Comment: It's entirely possible its CPU as well, but you haven't given us much info. If it was a cooling issue you could easily look at the CPU temp. If it spikes above 60-70*C idle, then you likely have a cooling issue. 

As others have mentioned, a simple hardware test will give you the answer. Run a memtest, prime95, storage benchmark, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, I will do what you've mentioned and edit my question adding more details.